# Ruby on Rails - Puma on_worker_boot connect with redis

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, heroku, redis, puma

I'm trying to connect with redis on heroku using Puma but I keep running into the error

`Read error: #<Redis::CannotConnectError: Error connecting to Redis on 127.0.0.1:6379 (Errno::ECONNREFUSED)>`

I've searched stackoverflow but none of the answers seem to fix my issue.

My `puma.rb` config

```
workers Integer(ENV['WEB_CONCURRENCY'] || 2)
threads_count = Integer(ENV['MAX_THREADS'] || 5)
threads threads_count, threads_count

preload_app!

rackup      DefaultRackup
port        ENV['PORT']     || 3000
environment ENV['RACK_ENV'] || 'development'

on_worker_boot do
  ActiveRecord::Base.establish_connection

  Redis.current.client.reconnect
  $redis = Redis.current
end
```

My `redis.rb` initializer

```
$redis = Redis.new(:url => ENV["REDISCLOUD_URL"])
```

I checked `ENV["REDISCLOUD_URL"]` that is `redis://rediscloud:blank@blank.eu-west-1-1.1.ec2.garantiadata.com:port`

I can't figure out what I am doing wrong, it all seems correct to me

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I had to set config var `heroku config:set REDIS_PROVIDER=REDISCLOUD_URL`

`Puma.rb`

```
workers Integer(ENV['WEB_CONCURRENCY'] || 2)
threads_count = Integer(ENV['MAX_THREADS'] || 5)
threads threads_count, threads_count

preload_app!

rackup      DefaultRackup
port        ENV['PORT']     || 3000
environment ENV['RACK_ENV'] || 'development'

on_worker_boot do
  ActiveRecord::Base.establish_connection

  if ENV["REDISCLOUD_URL"]
    uri = URI.parse(ENV["REDISCLOUD_URL"])
    Redis.current = Redis.new(host: uri.host, port: uri.port, password: uri.password)
    $redis = Redis.current
  else
    Redis.current.quit
  end
end
```

`redis.rb`

```
if ENV["REDISCLOUD_URL"]
  uri = URI.parse(ENV["REDISCLOUD_URL"])
  $redis = Redis.new(host: uri.host, port: uri.port, password: uri.password)
end
```

Comment: Reference: https://github.com/mperham/sidekiq/wiki/Using-Redis#using-an-env-variable